# Downgrade Heroku premium PostgreSQL tier to standard?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

How hard is it to downgrade a premium Postgres tier to standard?

Does it just require that I create a standard tier as a follower and then swap once the follower is caught up?

Or, ideally, is there an easier (single push-button) way to convert a premium tier to a standard tier (or vice versa)?

Answer (score 11):

Yes Mike Curtiss, is easier but follow part of the same steps, the quick how to is:

```
# first, list your databases
heroku pg -a <your-app-name>

# In my case, my current database is named PUCE and my old database is named WHITE, I want to copy the data from PUCE to WHITE
heroku pg:copy HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PUCE_URL HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_WHITE_URL -a <your-app-name>

# now, I just need to make WHITE the active database
heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_WHITE_URL -a <your-app-name>
```

Thats it. Then I remove the PUCE from the resources panel.

Oh, you need to have heroku toolbelt installed to run those commands. Install it from here https://toolbelt.heroku.com/

Answer (score 6):

## Two ways to Downgrade Heroku premium PostgreSQL tier to standard or Upgrade

- first, list your databases

  `heroku pg -a < your app name >`

> In my case, my current database is named PUCE and my old database is named WHITE, I want to copy the data from PUCE to WHITE

`heroku pg:copy HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PUCE_URL HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_WHITE_URL -a <your-app-name>`

> now, Unfollow PUCE

`heroku pg:unfollow HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PUCE_URL -a <your-app-name>`

> now, Just pramote the databse

`heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_WHITE_URL -a <your-app-name>`

> I have also restart dynos by 
>     `heroku ps:restart -a <your-app-name>`

- **Second Way**

> Create a new follower for your database and wait for the follower to
>   catch up to the primary database:

`heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:standard-2 --follow HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PUCE_URL -a <your-app-name>`

> Follower will become available for read-only queries when up-to-date
>   Use `heroku pg:wait` to track status

`heroku pg:wait -a <your-app-name>`

`heroku pg:info -a <your-app-name>`

> Following:   HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PUCE (DATABASE_URL)
>   Behind By:   125 commits

`heroku maintenance:on -a <your-app-name>`

`heroku pg:info -a <your-app-name>`

> Following:   HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PUCE_URL (DATABASE_URL)
>   Behind By:   0 commits
>   Check again pg info if it shoes behind by 0 than you can process below >query

`heroku pg:unfollow HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_WHITE_URL -a <your-app-name>`
`heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_WHITE -a <your-app-name>`

> Promoting HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_WHITE_URL to DATABASE_URL... done

`heroku maintenance:off -a <your-app-name>`

[refrence](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/updating-heroku-postgres-databases#updating-with-follower-changeover)

Comment: when I try to promote I get `is not a follower`

Answer (score 1):

There is no push-button way to downgrade.  I asked Heroku tech support about the question, and they said downgrading follows the exact same process as upgrading (i.e. creating a follower tier and then switching over).

Answer (score 0):

You could try forking the database on the new plan and promoting it once you're happy.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-fork